# Highcharts how to get columns to show correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe5/1/

```
var rangeStart = {1386828000000: 1333256400000}; //used in the tooltip
var rangeEnd = {1386828000000: 1364706000000}; //used in the tooltip

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    marginBottom: 25,
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        lineColor: '#000000',
        lineWidth: 2,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var myDate = new Date(this.value);
                var newDateMs = Date.UTC(myDate.getUTCFullYear(), myDate.getUTCMonth(), myDate.getUTCDate());
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%Y', newDateMs);
            },
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date',
            style: {
                color: 'black',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} %',
            step: 1,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#000000'
            }
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        lineColor: '#000000',
        lineWidth: 2,
        gridLineColor: null,
        minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: 2,
        minorTickColor: '#000000',
        minorTickLength: 5,
        minorTickWidth: 2,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside'
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var start = new Date(rangeStart[this.x]);
            var end = new Date(rangeEnd[this.x]);
            var startDate = Date.UTC(start.getUTCFullYear(), start.getUTCMonth(), start.getUTCDate());
            var endDate = Date.UTC(end.getUTCFullYear(), end.getUTCMonth(), end.getUTCDate());
            return '<span style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' %</b></span><br /><span style="color:#2F7ED8;">Date range</span><br />' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e/%Y', start) + ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%e/%Y', end);
        },
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    legend: {
        symbolPadding: 10,
        itemDistance: 23,
        symbolWidth: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        align: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        floating: false,
        width: 600
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'data1',
        data: [
            [1386828000000, 1]/*,
            [1389228000000, 0]*/ //if uncommented, mostly works
        ],
        color: '#a3052c'
    }, {
        name: 'data2',
        data: [
            [1386828000000, 3]/*,
            [1389228000000, 0]*/ //if uncommented, mostly works
        ],
        color: '#faa738'
    }, {
        name: 'data1',
        data: [
            [1386828000000, 6]/*,
            [1389228000000, 0]*/ //if uncommented, mostly works
        ],
        color: '#002144'
    }, {
        name: 'data4',
        data: [
            [1386828000000, 3]/*,
            [1389228000000, 0]*/ //if uncommented, mostly works
        ],
        color: '#008001'
    }]
});
```

It should be displaying with 4 individual columns (like http://jsfiddle.net/VrgW7/), but for some reason they all seem to be stacking on top of each other.  I can get it to display mostly correct by using a hack (uncomment `[1389228000000, 0]` in each series), but then it's behaving like there are 2 sets of data.

I've tried adding:

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        stacking: 'null' //or 'normal' or 'percent'
    }
},
```

but it didn't change the display as I want it to (it actually stacked them... I guess as expected).

Everything is correct in my jsfiddle (data values, tooltip) except the way it's displaying.  Does anybody have any suggestions on what to change to get it to display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here has to do with scaling I think. If we change all your timestamps to `15` we get individual columns. So, what I did was set the `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max` to be just outside of the dates of your data:

```
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: 1386827000000,
            max: 1389229000000,
....
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe5/3/).

Comment: that's definitely closer, but I don't want to have to use a second data point to get it to display correctly.  If I remove the second data point for each series (`[1389228000000, 6/7/8/9]`) and change the min/max to be only 1 higher/lower, it is very close to what I want (http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe5/4/), but the widths of the lines still aren't what they would be if the data points were `15`.  Is this unavoidable because I'm working with such high values, and it just can't scale well at this point?

Comment: You could always adjust the `pointWidth`: http://jsfiddle.net/bfqe5/5/. I set it on each series but you can use `plotOptions.series{}` to set it for all series.